# strtok function does not function properly

Tags: c

LOG.txt file :

```
2327 - Your account is created on 01/09/15 # 
2327 - Amount:100 withfrawed from your account on 01/09/15 #
```

This code show me a output at first time compilation and other other output at second time                        compilation. What is the mistake i have make

```
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
FILE *fp;

void main()
{
    int i=0;   
    char temp[10],log[10000],*token;
    char s1[2] = "#",s2[2] = "-",logger[100][70],no[100][10];
    clrscr();

    fp=fopen("LOG.TXT","r");

    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",temp)!=EOF)
    {
        strcat(log,temp);
        strcat(log," ");
    } 
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s",log);
    token = strtok(log,s1);

    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(logger[i],token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL,s1);
    }

    i=0;
    token = strtok(logger[i],s2);
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(no[i],token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(logger[i],s2);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: well, at first look, it seems, you did not use a null terminated string for `strcat()`.

Comment: Also, there is no need to parse twice for two separate delimiter. You can use `char * del = " #-"` at once. And always check for the success of `fopen()`

Comment: Sorry, but by pasting your code, you are saying exactly what you are doing, not what you want to do.  Computers always do what they are told, not what they are meant to do.  You are for sure making the same mistake (as you complaint you are indeed doing) with us than whit your computer.  How can we know what exactly you do want to do and what have you missed?

Answer (score 2):

```
char log[10000];
```

Here `log` is uninitialized so `strcat()` will search for NULL terminator and `log` will not have it because it is unintialized so you need to initialize `log` before doing `strcat()`

Using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behavior so `strtok()` not working might be because of this.

You can do

```
char log[10000] = {0};
```

or

```
memset(log,0,sizeof(log));
```

Comment: can i initialise log as null

Comment: @leopragi You can check the edits of what can be done

Comment: better `char log[10000] = "";` don't?

Comment: @LuisColorado Better in which way?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
strcat(log,temp);
strcat(log," ");
```

You do not initialize `log` which means the contents is *indeterminate* and using `log` this way leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Remember that `strcat` looks for the string terminator character `'\0'` to know where it should start appending, and uninitialized local non-static variables will have seemingly random contents.

Comment: The OP probably should `memset(log, 0, sizeof(log));` very early in his program.

Comment: If i initialise log it show all the string as (null)

Comment: isn't it like the `while() {}` loop should be under `if(fp)`?